# Making a ListView that expand Horizontally and Vertically

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Basically, I'm trying to do a ListView or GridView that contains the rounded red containers. If the container is big enough so that it can't fit in one line, it must go to the other line.

[image]

This code is just what I did for the image. But I want to switch this for a single ListView or GridView.

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    TagContainer(name: 'LoreIpsumLoreIpsum'),
    SizedBox(width: 8.0),
    TagContainer(name: 'LoreIpsum'),
  ],
),
SizedBox(height: 8.0),
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    TagContainer(name: 'LoreIpsum'),
    SizedBox(width: 8.0),
    TagContainer(name: 'LoreIpsumLore'),
    SizedBox(width: 8.0),
    TagContainer(name: 'Lore'),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want here is the **Wrap** widget: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5iw2SeFx2M

Try something like this:

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0,
  children: <Widget> [
    TagContainer(name: 'LoreIpsumLoreIpsum'),
    TagContainer(name: 'LoreIpsum'),
    TagContainer(name: 'LoreIpsum'),
    TagContainer(name: 'LoreIpsumLore'),
    TagContainer(name: 'Lore')
  ]
)
```